# reading file : bad syntax (multiple expressions after identifier)

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

```
(define bootstrap-c-code
    (define (from-file file-name)
       (let* ((ip (open-input-file file-name))
            (res (read-text-file-from-input-port ip)))
         (close-input-port ip)
         res))
    (from-file "llvm.c"))
```

Error : define: bad syntax (multiple expressions after identifier)

But I can't see anything wrong with it. Can someone explain / fix it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you intended with the above code. If you were trying to load a text file and leave the loaded value in a **variable** called `bootstrap-c-code`, then try this:

```
(define bootstrap-c-code
  (let ((from-file
         (lambda (file-name)
           (let* ((ip (open-input-file file-name))
                  (res (read-text-file-from-input-port ip)))
             (close-input-port ip)
             res))))
    (from-file "llvm.c")))
```

Of course, the `from-file` definition will only be visible inside the `let`, if you need to use it outside, `define` it outside of the whole expression. If you only need the functionality of `from-file` inside the `let`, you can obtain the same result in a much simpler way:

```
(define bootstrap-c-code
  (let* ((ip  (open-input-file "llvm.c"))
         (res (read-text-file-from-input-port ip)))
    (close-input-port ip)
    res))
```

On the other hand, if what you intended was to create a **procedure** called `bootstrap-c-code`, then the correct syntax would be:

```
(define (bootstrap-c-code)
  (define (from-file file-name)
    (let* ((ip (open-input-file file-name))
           (res (read-text-file-from-input-port ip)))
      (close-input-port ip)
      res))
  (from-file "llvm.c"))
```

Comment: Good! Then consider passing "llvm.c" as a parameter to the function, instead of hard coding that value

Comment: but wait... it doesn't work :( reference to undefined identifier: read-text-file-from-input-port

Comment: That `read-text-file-from-input-port` was in the code of your question, I just assumed that you had the implementation for that! - besides, that was not the question, the question was what to do with the error "multiple expressions after identifier", and that was solved in my answer

Comment: added everything from http://cs.aau.dk/~normark/scheme/lib/man/file-read-ep/file-read-1.html#read-text-file-from-input-port ) now it works, sorry for mess.

Answer (score 1):

[According to R5RS](http://lavica.fesb.hr/cgi-bin/info2html?%28r5rs%29Internal%20definitions), internal definitions can occur only at the beginning of the  of a bunch of forms like let, let*, lambda etc. In the case of your code, that is not the case since you have an internal definition inside a non-procedural define. You could fix it by making `bootstrap-c-code' bind to a procedure.